# How to selected which tags to print, instead of printing the whole tag list?

Tags: post-meta, tags

When having this:

```
$tag_list = get_the_tag_list( '', ', ' );
```

I substituted the meta print:

```
printf(
$tag_list,
$category:list,
etc
);
```

by this:

```
$printArray_tag_list = explode(', ', $tag_list);
echo $category_list."/".$printArray_tag_list[0].','.$printArray_tag_list[1];
```

to print only the first two tags from the list (the first tags inserted in the post editor). Only then I realized that they are alphabetically ordered and those are not the tags I want to print.

Is there a way to print selected tags? Maybe selecting them in the custom fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `get_the_tags()` you receive an array of tags attached to the current post. So you could do the following:

```
$tags = get_the_tags();
$tag_ids_to_print = array( 1, 2, 3 ); //List of Tag IDs which you want to be printed

$print_tags = array();
if( is_array( $tags ) ){
    foreach( $tags as $tag ){
        if( in_array( $tag->term_id, $tag_ids_to_print ) )
            $print_tags[] = $tag;
    }
}

$tag_list = '';
if( count( $print_tags ) > 0 ){
    //Execute only, when tags found
    $i = 0;
    foreach( $print_tags as $tag ){
        if( $i == 1 ) $tag_list .= ', ';
        $tag_list .= '<a href="' . get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
        $i = 1;
    }
}
```

Docs:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags

Comment: +1 but you might want to handle the case when the post is without any tags to avoid PHP warnings.

Comment: thanks. i am not quite sure, i think you just get back an empty array so that count( $print_tags ) > 0 should be enough, but I added an if( is_array( $tags ) ) to be sure :)

Comment: ps: `get_the_tags()` returns `false` in that case, hence the possible PHP warnings.

Comment: thx. Good to know!

Comment: This goes in my functions.php and then I printf($tag_list in my content-single.php, as usual? @websupporter

Comment: no, this approach would be part of the template file. you would use in instead of the_tag_list().

Comment: Glad you're there. I need to add this in between the code that will print the categories then. Not sure I'm able to. Here is what I have in content-single.php

Comment: <?php
     $category_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'virality' ) );

       $tag_list = get_the_tag_list( '', ', ' );

       if ( ! virality_categorized_blog() ) {
        if ( '' != $tag_list ) {
         $meta_text = __( 'tagged %2$s', 'virality' );
        } 

       } else {
    
        if ( '' != $tag_list ) {
         $meta_text = __( 'Posted in %1$s / tagged %2$s', 'virality' );
        } else {
         $meta_text = __( 'Posted in %1$s', 'virality' );
        }

       } 
        printf(
        $category_list,
        $tag_list
       );
      ?>

Comment: please update your question accordingly.

Comment: but i updated the code. use this instead of  $tag_list = get_the_tag_list( '', ', ' ); should work.

Comment: Couldn't fix the messy comment here above.

I'll rethink my approach as I can have a hard time understanding how to do this. Thanks for pointing out a direction.  I like the idea of having the selected tags be printed in an automated way. But maybe I'll research more on the answer from birgire and have the authors insert the tags to be displayed through custom fields.

Just saw your comment.I'll give it a try then. Thanks!

Comment: I inserted your code in substitution of ` $tag_list = get_the_tag_list( '', ', ' );` No tags printed. Only categories. And I'm not able to tell why.

Comment: Probably you need to add the following code at the place, where you want to see the taglist: <?php printf( $meta_text, $tag_list ) ?>

Comment: the $meta_text and the $category_list are being printed, but not the $tag_list. Not the $meta_text from the tag_list either.

Comment: did you alter the $tag_ids_to_print accordingly? Maybe its better you try it with birgires approach, which seems to be a bit more non-programmer-friendly :)

Comment: Yes, I understand birgire's method better, even that it didn't work. I'll digg into it now.
Where would I alter that variable "accordingly"? $tag_ids_to_print ?

Comment: I'll digg into that link you shared. Thanks for being there @websupporter

Comment: I got what you mean with $tag_ids_to_print. I substituted 1, 2, 3 by tag Ids and it printed them out. But what I was looking for was to print out automatically the 1st, 2nd and 3rd (order of insertion, not allphabetic) tags of a post. Maybe it's easier to have them printed after having them manually selected through a custom field. I'll reformulate in another question. I've done this before for adding text so it must be easy to call the tags that correspond to the text we insert in the custom field.

Answer (score 1):

### Custom Field Tag filter:

You can try the following code snippet to filter tags from a custom field:

```
/**
 * Support the 'include_tags' custom field (comma seperated tag slugs) 
 * to filter out those tags to display.
 *
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/183929/26350
 */

! is_admin() && add_filter( 'get_the_terms', function( $terms, $post_id, $taxonomy )
{
    if(    'post_tag' === $taxonomy 
        && ! empty( $terms ) 
        && $include = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'include_tags', true ) 
    ){      
        // We only want lower case and trimmed strings from the custom meta field:
        $include_tags = array_map( 'trim', array_map( 'strtolower', explode( ',', $include ) ) );

        // Let's filter out the terms to display:
        if( ! empty( $include_tags ) )
            $terms = array_filter( $terms, function( $t ) use ( $include_tags ) {               
                return in_array( $t->slug, $include_tags );
            });
    }
    return $terms;
}, 10, 3 );
```

For example if you use `the_tags()` in your template and have the following tags in a given post:

[image: tags]

then you can add the custom field `include_tags` with a comma seperated list of tags you want to filter out:

[image: cf]

Then it will show like this on your front end:

[image: display]

Similarly we could support `exclude_tags` filtering with:

```
return ! in_array( $t->slug, $include_tags );
```

instead.